# Jboss successfull event is not firing

Tags: security, jsf, jboss5.x, seam2

We have Seam application, we have following code

```
if( isLoginSuccess(userId,Passwor) ){
    Identity.instance().login();
}
```

and in component.xml we have configuration

```
<event type="org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful">
        <action execute="#{defaultPageRedirector.returnToCapturedView()}"/>
    </event>
```

Every time isLoginSuccess(userId,Passwor) return true ( we know that ) but only sometime ( randomly ) returnToCapturedView() is called , its happening randomly.

Could you please help me in this regards

Answer (score 0):

If it is happening randomly there is something wrong with your **defaultPageRedirector** check [seam redirect](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.seam/jboss-seam/2.1.2/org/jboss/seam/faces/Redirect.java).

According to [Seam Identity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.seam/jboss-seam/2.1.2/org/jboss/seam/security/Identity.java), This event raises only if user is not loggedIn Or user is loogedIn but siletnLogin attribute is set.

Answer (score 0):

where are you getting defaultPageRedirector from? Is this your own version of seams Redirect component?

Is should be:

```
<event type="org.jboss.seam.security.loginSuccessful">
    <action execute="#{redirect.returnToCapturedView}"/>
</event>
```